# ls add host name prefix?

Tags: ssh, sed, ls, paste

Is there a compact way to list files, with the host name prepended? My efforts to combine `ls`, `xargs`, `paste` and process substitution have failed me.

This is the best I came up with:

```
ls * | paste  <(echo $HOST)
```

Ultimately I want to list a bunch of files across multiple hosts by invoking a series of ssh commands so that I can do something like this:

```
ssh host1 "ls_with_hostname_prefix /var/log/*"
ssh host2 "ls_with_hostname_prefix /var/log/*"
ssh host3 "ls_with_hostname_prefix /var/log/*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line). You can simply do

```
ls | sed -e 's/^/$HOST /'
```

You probably want to store it as a script on the remote hosts or merge it even with the `ssh`:

```
function remote_ls_with_alias() {
  ssh $1 "ls $2 | sed -e \"s/^/$1 /\""
}
```

and run it as

```
remote_ls_with_alias host1 "/var/log/*"
remote_ls_with_alias host2 "/var/log/*"
remote_ls_with_alias host3 "/var/log/*"
```

Comment: Man that's so obvious and I completely missed it, trying to be clever with the much less useful `paste` command.

Comment: Just a note to anyone else reading: Double quotes so hostname gets resolved. (I'd edit it myself but stack overflow says my edits are too short)